# How to unit test permissions in a React Admin controller?

Tags: jestjs, react-admin

I'm using react-admin and I have a list component that has some conditional display behavior based on permissions.

I'd like to write a simple Jest test that asserts the correct behavior (display the Edit button if admin, hide the Edit button if not admin), but I need to feed some mock records into my list component. How do I pass mock data to my list component?

Comment: Actually, it's a really good question. I opened a PR aiming to improving the documentation: https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin/pull/2728
Let me know if it's clear to you!

Comment: Oh, that's awesome! I found your documentation very helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is (now) a dedicated paragraph on the documentation about testing permissions-based view: https://marmelab.com/react-admin/UnitTesting.html#testing-permissions

I also wrote [an example of unit test available on the code base: UnitShow.spec.js](https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin/blob/8decbed87f753a2d8397fc9af43fde5fb862293c/examples/simple/src/users/UserShow.spec.js)

```
 it('should show the user role in the second tab', () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(<UserShow permissions="admin" />);

    const tabs = wrapper.find(Tab);
    const fields = tabs.at(1).find(TextField);

    expect(fields.at(0).prop('source')).toBe('role');
});
```